# How to get text-wrapping for source code elements while using rmarkdown/bookdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, bookdown

I'm using bookdown to prepare some documents. Below is the simple minimal reproducible example:

````
---
papersize: a6
site: bookdown::bookdown_site

output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    keep_tex: true

---

This paragraph has inline code (really it is SHA512 sum of some object) - `2a46edf77d12d5e4f71c0ffc5fa7e7ea3ae6d96667a3d39ba8658eb5de634ee48669e6bc366509e516ba7ecda6986c52ee8cab751660a789b6d55a1c8dc8296c`.

The code block is below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

other style with highlightning:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```
````

The source code lines are too long.

[image: rendering of above example]

What should I add to preamble to allow code wrapping (breaking in multiple lines) like for example as shown below?

> ```
> 2a46edf77d12d5e4f71c0ffc5fa7e7ea3a
> e6d96667a3d39ba8658eb5de634ee48669e  
> 6bc366509e516ba7ecda6986c52ee8cab75
> 1660a789b6d55a1c8dc8296c
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
> content="text/html; 
> charset=utf-8">
> ```

Update: adding

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{listings} \let\verbatim\undefined \let\verbatimend\undefined \lstnewenvironment{verbatim}{\lstset{breaklines,basicstyle=\ttfamily}}{}
```

helps to solve problem with plain code, but I found that I'm using some code fragments with highlighting.

The intermediate LaTeX is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/T8tEdxq9).

Comment: Same question: can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks, [here it is](https://pastebin.com/raw/7c7fw6j5) .

Comment: For the first part you could try with `\usepackage{seqsplit}` in the header include and then `\seqsplit{\ttfamily 2a46edf77d12d5e4f71c0ffc5fa7e7ea3ae6d96667a3d39ba8658eb5de634ee48669e6bc366509e516ba7ecda6986c52ee8cab751660a789b6d55a1c8dc8296c}` in your document

Comment: For the second part it would be better to use a suitable environment like `lstlistings` from the `listings` package that supports linebreaks, but no idea how to convince markdown to do this. You could try `\usepackage{listings}
\let\verbatim\undefined
\let\verbatimend\undefined
\lstnewenvironment{verbatim}{\lstset{breaklines,basicstyle=\ttfamily}}{}` but no guarantee that this won't spectacularly break some other things...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the first part is currently not universal. Do you have any ideas? The second is working. But I found that it does not work for blocks with highlighting (they use `Shaded` and `Highlighting` commands). Could you please check [new LaTeX file](https://pastebin.com/raw/T8tEdxq9) and suggest solution for inline and Shaded blocks?

Comment: For highlighting, try `\usepackage{fvextra}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}`

Comment: What do you mean with `not universal`?

Comment: I have a problem - on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS there is no `fvextra.sty` file in the `texlive-latex-extra` package. Without it I get "! Package keyval Error: breaklines undefined.". Is it any alternative? By "not universal" I mean - I can't understand how to enter `\seqsplit{\ttfamily 2a46edf77d12d5e4f71c0ffc5fa7e7ea3ae6d96667a3d39ba8658eb5de634ee48669e6bc366509e516ba7ecda6986c52ee8cab751660a789b6d55a1c8dc8296c}` in RMarkdown document. It will not render for HTML, DOCX and other output formats...

Comment: Your texlive is probably too old. `fvextra` should be included in full versions of texlive 2017 or newer. My usual advice is to install a full version of vanilla texlive directly from the TUG website instead of using the one included in ubuntu: 1) you will have all packages 2) much more up-to-date than the outdated versions included in most linux distros

Comment: true, the `seqsplit` approach will only work in pdf output. The fundamental problem is that `\texttt{...}` is really the most unsuitable way one can render inline code. rmarkdown should really no translate the inline code into this. Of course one could redefine `\texttt` but this is such a fundamental macro that many other things might break

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221057/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Please post all the snippets as answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: Done, although I think using them is really a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**

The following code snippets are just hacky workarounds, in particular the third one does not work in general and has the ability to break a great many things... instead of using them, please try convince the tool, that creates the tex code, to use suitable environments and macros.

To add line breaks to the `Verbatim` environment:

```
\usepackage{listings} 
\let\verbatim\undefined 
\let\verbatimend\undefined 
\lstnewenvironment{verbatim}{\lstset{breaklines,basicstyle=\ttfamily}}{}
```

To add line breaks to the `Highlight` environment:

```
\usepackage{fvextra} 
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
```

To add line breaks to your hash code

```
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{{\ttfamily\seqsplit{#1}}}
```

(to say this again, I don't recommend redefining `\texttt`, that's really not a good idea, but the OP insisted...)

Comment: I made an edit for verbatim environment as well. You are correct about the premise, but I'm really happy with the solution provided by these hacks. They are simpler than modifying bookdown→rmarkdown→knitr→pandoc chain by creating custom TeX-template or something more complex and difficult. All I need is to get adequate PDF file. The other possible solution is to use the [pagedown](https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown), but it requires adaption of the HTML+CSS template which is time-consuming procedure. So your solution is absolutely what I need. Thank you!